# DevTools Bug: Cannot add node "1" because a node with that id is already in the Store

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo, react-native-debugger

I am using [React native debugger tool](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) in the expo-based react native project.

I am getting the below error when running the debugger

[image: Cannot add node "1" because a node with that id is already in the Store.]

and when I dismiss the error I see the following screen

[image: Unsupported DevTools backend version]

To fix the above issue, I have added `react-devtools: 4.24.1` and `react-devtools-core: 4.24.1` as project dev dependencies but it still didn't work.

Any suggestions on how this can be fixed?

```
React Native version: 0.64.3
OS: macOS Monterey
expo Version: 44.0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first part of the question with the "1" NODE, I am not sure about that fix as I'm still researching it and getting it occasionally.

As for your second part of the downgrade/upgrade problem, I found that I had a global installation of the react-devtools-core of 4.24.1 while my react-devtools in my project was on 4.14.0. To fix it, I first removed any global install, and to find any global instals, you should use the {`npm ls -g`} command or the {`npm list -g`}. That should show you if you have the react devtools installed globally, and if you do, just do a {`npm uninstall -g react-devtools & npm uninstall -g react-devtools-core`}.

Once the global versions are uninstalled, I went back into my project, and {`rm package-lock.json & rm -rf node_modules`} and then {`npm install`} to reset the state of the project. Once there, you can do {`npm explain react-devtools-core`} to find out what version it's using and from which package it's getting its version from. You should then be able to do a {`npm install -d react-devtools-core@4.14.0`} (or whatever version it is complaining about. You may have to do this again for the react-devtools but in my case, it was just the "core" that was a different version.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `{ StrictMode }` mode in index.js file ,then save